# show that $A, A^2, ..., A^k$ are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

I am hoping that someone could review my solution. Thanks!

> for A (a matrix), $A:V\rightarrow V$ and every $v$ in $V$, the vectors $v, A(v), A^2(v), ..., A^k(v)$ are linearly dependent where $k$ is a natural number $\leq \dim(V)$.
>
> show that $A, A^2, ..., A^k$ are linearly dependent

Thanks for the feedback in advance!

Comment: Your $c_i$s are $0$ by assumption so that sum will equal $0$ independent of what you put in place of the $A^kv$s. By the way, I believe you mistyped your title.

Comment: The very beginning of your proof is flawed: if all the coefficients are zero all the rest in irrelevant.

Comment: I have edited the proof as a second attempt, could you please review it? @DonAntonio

Comment: @JohnDouma, I have re-edited my original post and was wondering if you could review it as a second attempt. Thanks!

Comment: I saw that. You and I made the same mistake. We forgot to include $v$ along with the $A^kv$ terms. I have a two sentence proof below.

Comment: @JohnDouma, would u be able to review my new proof? I completely changed it from the first iteration and I believe it proves it for all K

Comment: Your proof looks essentially correct now. Some suggestions: change some $v$ to all $v$ and I don't believe you need to quote the rank nullity theorem. You can just state that the rank is $0$ from the fact that all vectors get mapped to $0$. Then I'd say you are good.

Comment: great! thanks! I had one thought that maybe my assumption that the left side of the equation is equal to the zero vector may be jumping to conclusions... could one also conclude that the left side is a non zero matrix and in fact indicates a contradiction?

Comment: Wait. You are still assuming what you want to prove. You have to include a $c_0v$ term in your sum to assume linear dependence.

Comment: Your $c_i$ depends on vector $v$ , they can't be factorized

Comment: ahh yes, not really assuming what i want to prove, but omitting something making my job easier... i think when u include it breaks it since u end up with a coefficient plus a matrix which doesnt make sense...

Comment: @Damien, u mean when i pull out the "v" from the sum? Isnt that allowed due to it being a scalar and a linear transformation A?

Comment: The problem is just after, when you assume the same $c_i$ can be used for all vectors $v$

Comment: but i couldve applied the coefficient multiplication on the step before, ended up with different matrices across the board, and then pulled out the V and then you wouldn't have a complaint right? then it seems simply pulling out the previous c_i would work...

Comment: linear transformations can be summed and scalars pulled out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true as written. Consider the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^3$. For every $v$, $\{v, Iv\}$ is linearly dependent but $\{I\}$ isn't.

Comment: great, thanks! I didn't post this question originally, I'm now curious where the person got the problem from. Don't see false proofs in textbooks very often!

Comment: @H_1317 I had to read this problem a couple of times. Maybe our first interpretation was correct but I am not sure. By the way. You shouldn't delete your work on a question. Someone who wasn't here tonight may see just the question and downvote it because they don't realize how much work you put into it.

Comment: the first interpretation seemed too easy to me. simply taking the k = dim(v) case that is

Comment: @H_1317 I believe that the statement should have read: Show that $I,A,A^2,...,A^k$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that the zero coefficients lead to zero sum of $A^k$ can't prove that there is no other linear combinations of $A^k(v)$ equal to zero. You only assigned same coefficients from $c_1A + c_2A^2 + ... + c_kA^k$, but can't prove it is a must.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. This is more a comment...

Comment: The question asks for a review. I don't have comment authority, but I think the flaw is like that.

Answer (score 0):

Say $c_0I+c_1A+c_2A^2+...+c_kA^k=O$.

Post-multiply by $v$, we have $c_0v+c_1Av+c_2A^2v+...+c_kA^kv=\bf0$. Since $v,Av,A^2v,...,A^kv$ are linearly dependent, we have a non-trivial tuple $(c_0,c_1,c_2,...,c_k)$ which satisfies the above relation. Therefore, the best you can say is that $I,A,A^2,...,A^k$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks! This was actually a similar technique to a previous attempt of mine